# Xml merge using C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, c#-3.0

```
xml1:
<value>
    <Id>1</id>
    <name>AAA</name>
</value>
<value>
    <Id>2</id>
    <name>bbb</name>
</value>
<value>
    <Id>3</id>
    <name>ccc</name>
</value>

xml2:

<value>
<Id>1</id>
<Company>abc</Company>
<address>ASD</address>
</value>

result :
    <value>
        <Id>1</id>
        <name>AAA</name>
        <Company>abc</Company>
        <address>ASD</address>
    </value>
    <value>
        <Id>2</id>
        <name>bbb</name>
    </value>
    <value>
        <Id>3</id>
        <name>ccc</name>
    </value>
```

if id of 1st xml = 2nd xml then merge the 2nd xml record with 1st xml value record.
In my code i havnt checked id values but im juz trying to merge the 2nd xml record along with root with 1xml record. it will be great if u help me out. im getting error has  The node to be inserted is from a different document context.

```
 XmlNode x1 = doc1.SelectSingleNode("/OutLooksync/value");
            foreach (XmlNode node in x1.SelectNodes("/OutLooksync/value"))
            {
                x1.AppendChild(doc2.ImportNode(node, true));

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `XmlDocument`,

- you could loop in the *values* in `xml1` and in the *values* in `xml2`
- Check if `id` equals, and import `childNodes` from `xml2`

1 - Xml for test:

```
string xml1 = @"
    <OutLooksync>
        <value>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>AAA</name>
        </value>
        <value>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>bbb</name>
        </value>
        <value>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>ccc</name>
        </value>
    </OutLooksync>";

string xml2 = @"
    <OutLooksync>
        <value>
            <id>1</id>
            <Company>abc</Company>
            <address>ASD</address>
        </value>
    </OutLooksync>";
```

2 - code for importing nodes

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument1 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument1.LoadXml(xml1);

XmlDocument xmlDocument2 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument2.LoadXml(xml2);

XmlNodeList values1 = xmlDocument1.SelectNodes("/OutLooksync/value");
XmlNodeList values2 = xmlDocument2.SelectNodes("/OutLooksync/value");

foreach(XmlNode value1 in values1)
{
    foreach(XmlNode value2 in values2)
    {
        if(value1.SelectSingleNode("./id").InnerText != value2.SelectSingleNode("./id")?.InnerText)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        foreach(XmlNode toImport in value2.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (toImport.Name == "id")
                continue;

            value1.AppendChild(xmlDocument1.ImportNode(toImport, true));
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument1.InnerXml);
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: im still working on it, i have made some changes in your code if it works then  i wil accept ur ans

Comment: @MadhavaSM this code gives the expected result. if you have any question, i will explain it to you. the code checks if the values match by id, so takes children from value in xml2 expected id and put it in value that exist in xml1.

Comment: it works fine thnx bro. i need small change like 2nd xml record should not be replaced with 1xml value record but it should display under it eg.. <value>
        <Id>1</id>
        <name>AAA</name><value>
        <Company>abc</Company>
        <address>ASD</address></value>
    </value> is  this possible??

Comment: Can i knw why u used != in if condition

Comment: @MadhavaSM for 2 question : `value1.SelectSingleNode("./id").InnerText != value2.SelectSingleNode("./id")?.InnerText` means : if the id in value from xml not equals id in value from xml2, then check the next value in xml2. for the 1 question i will add the code, you don't need the 3 foreach in the code, just delete id from value in imported it to xml1.

Comment: can u modify the if code has i required " if(b.contains(a))" where a ="1"  b ="1" bcz i have files which i couldnt share with u. but this logic works for my sample logic.

Comment: if(value1.SelectSingleNode("./id").InnerText.contains( value2.SelectSingleNode("./id")?.InnerText))
        
        foreach(XmlNode toImport in value2.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (toImport.Name == "id")
                continue;

            value1.AppendChild(xmlDocument1.ImportNode(toImport, true));
        }} i tried working fine thnx

Comment: @MadhavaSM but contains will create an issue, if id in xml `111` and in xml2 `1` ==> contains gives true, and `==` gives false. i think you should use `==` or `.Equals()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
            string xml1 = @"
    <OutLooksync>
        <value>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>AAA</name>
        </value>
        <value>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>bbb</name>
        </value>
        <value>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>ccc</name>
        </value>
    </OutLooksync>";

            string xml2 = @"
    <OutLooksync>
        <value>
            <id>4</id>
            <Company>abc</Company>
            <address>ASD</address>
        </value>
    </OutLooksync>";
            XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            doc1.LoadXml(xml1);

            XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            doc2.LoadXml(xml2);
            XmlNode newvalue = doc1.ImportNode(doc2.DocumentElement.FirstChild, true);
            doc1.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newvalue);
```

Comment: this code works but not according to my logic , xml2 should hav id value of 1 so it should merge with xml1 id value of 1

Comment: doc1.SelectSingleNode("/OutLooksync/value").AppendChild(newvalue); this one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
XmlNodeList x1 = doc1.SelectSingleNodes("/OutLooksync/value");
    foreach (XmlNode node in x1)
        {
            doc2.appendChild(node);

         }
```

Comment: im getting error cannot convert implicitly xmlnode to xmlnodelist. if i use xmlnode then im getting  the node to be inserted is from a different document context.

Comment: doc2.SelectSingleNode("/OutLooksync").appendChild(node);

Comment: object reference errror bro

Comment: @MadhavaSM it's not simple to do that by 4 lines of code